# youtube複数動画（cuePlaylist利用）の途中再生について

Tags: javascript, youtube

YouTubeのIframeAPIを使って、再生リスト（cuePlaylistを使って、複数のyoutube動画を再生させる）
のプログラムを作成しておりますが、下記の部分がどうすればよいかわかりません。
ご教示、お願いいたします。

【やりたいこと】
1. htmlファイルを開いたときに、動画再生リストが自動的に再生を始める。
2. 動画を再生中に、別のページへ移動。
3. 再度戻った時に、途中から再生を始める。

【できないこと】
3の「途中から再生を始める」という部分が、わかりません。
再生状況を取得するのがよいのか等、初心者なので、どうすればよいかわかりません。

ご教示をお願いいたします。

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="player"></div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var tag = document.createElement('script');
  tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
  var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
  firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

  var player;

  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('player', {
      height: '360',
      width: '640',

      playerVars: {
        rel: 0, 
        autoplay: 1,
        loop:1
      },

      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      },
    });
  }

  // 再生リスト
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    player.cuePlaylist([
      'v8N0Y2ETCl8',
      'P_WjrS6YjxA'
    ]);
  }

  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {

    // プレイヤーステートを取得する
    var state = player.getPlayerState();

    // 頭出し済み状態である
    if(state == YT.PlayerState.CUED){

      // 動画を再生する
      player.playVideo();
    }
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: HTMLファイル全体に謝り（追加）あります。

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="player"></div>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

上記で記載されているコード

</script>
</body>
</html>

Comment: harry0000様、編集ありがとうございます。助かります。